# NASM: copying a pointer from a register to a buffer in .data

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am new to asm. I am trying to copy a pointer from a register to a `.data` variable using NASM, on linux 64-bit.

Concider this program:

```
    section .data
ptr: dq 0

    section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov [ptr], rsp

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Here I try to copy the current stack pointer to `ptr`. `ptr` is declared as a quadword. Neither `nasm` nor the linker complains, but when debugging the program with gdb, I can see that both addresses are different:

```
gdb ./test.s
+(gdb) break _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b0
+(gdb) run
Starting program: test
Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004000b0 in _start ()
+(gdb) nexti
0x00000000004000b8 in _start ()
+(gdb) info registers
...
rsp            0x7fffffffe460   0x7fffffffe460
...
+(gdb) x ptr
0xffffffffffffe460: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffe460
```

From what I understand, `mov` should copy all 64 bits from `rsp` to `[ptr]`, but it seems that the most significant `0`s are not copied and/or that there is some kind of sign extension, as if only the least significant bits were copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you don't have debug info for the `ptr` type, so `gdb` treats it as integer. You can examine its real contents using:

```
(gdb) x/a &ptr
0x600124 <ptr>: 0x7fffffffe950
(gdb) p/a $rsp
$3 = 0x7fffffffe950
```

Of course I have a different value for `rsp` than you, but you can see that `ptr` and `rsp` match.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using gdb wrongly to me:

```
    section .data
ptr: dq 0

    section .text
    global main

main:
    mov [ptr], rsp
    ret
```

Compiling with:

```
rm -f test.o && nasm -f elf64 test.asm && gcc -m64 -o test test.o
```

Then my debugging session looks like this:

```
gdb ./test

(...)
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004c0
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/rr-/test 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004004c0 in main ()
(gdb) nexti
0x00000000004004c8 in main ()
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x4004c0 4195520
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0x0  0
rdx            0x7fffffffe388   140737488348040
rsi            0x7fffffffe378   140737488348024
rdi            0x1  1
rbp            0x4004d0 0x4004d0 <__libc_csu_init>
rsp            0x7fffffffe298   0x7fffffffe298
(...)
(gdb) info addr ptr
Symbol "ptr" is at 0x600880 in a file compiled without debugging.
(gdb) x/g 0x600880
0x600880:   140737488347800
```

140737488347800 evaluates to 0x7FFFFFFFE298 just fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
+(gdb) x/h ptr
```

`h` means half-word, which is two bytes. What you want is probably `g` (*Giant words* in GDB terminology, which is eight bytes).

Comment: Thanks for the precision, however using `g` doesn't change a thing. I don't think it is a gdb formatting problem (I found this issue because of a segfault). Note: I edited my question with `x ptr`, as they all